# SQL Order By Street Name then Street Number, Same Column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to order a list of addresses by street name, then street number. Both forms of this data reside in the same column, 'address' within my schema, 'data'.

The data have a similar format to:

- 27 Longshire Cir
- 109 Dewey Ln
- 26 Zeke Blvd
- 1 Longshire Cir
- 26 Albatross Rd

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY address;
```

Which gives me:

- 1 Longshire Cir
- 26 Albatross Rd
- 26 Zeke Blvd
- 27 Longshire Cir
- 109 Dewey Ln

I have also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM parcel_data.parcels ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, ' ', 1), UNSIGNED INTEGER);
```

Which gives me a list that has no attention to the order of alphabetization, but follows the numbers.
This would look something akin to:

- 1 Longshire Cir
- 26 Zeke Ln
- 26 Albatross Rd
- 27 Longshire Cir
- 109 Dewey Ln

Ideally, the output I'm looking for is:

- 26 Albatross Rd
- 109 Dewey Ln
- 1 Longshire Cir
- 27 Longshire Cir
- 26 Zeke Blvd

Putting alphabetization of street names first, then ordering the numbers.

How do I do that?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you would just do:

```
order by
  substring_index(address,' ',char_length(replace(address,' ',''))-char_length(address)),
  0+address,
  address
```

(the last just for non-numeric house numbers)

Comment: so I implemented that suggestion, although it still puts the numbers as the primary grouping method, where I need the alphabet to be more important. If it makes sense, I need all the Albatross Rd entries grouped in numerical order, then the Dewey Ln entries, then Longshire and Zeke in order of their numbers. Do you think it would be like a group by too?

Comment: sorry, I was misremembering how substring_index works; fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with using Locate & Reverse functions in mysql..I just extracted the middle name & sorted.

https://dbfiddle.uk/157f2xxv

select * from data order by (select substring(address,locate(" ",address),length(address)- (locate(" ",reverse(address))+locate(" ",address))))

Comment: don't mix length (which counts bytes) with locate (which counts characters); use char_length.

Comment: example: https://dbfiddle.uk/NBNdTxbu

Comment: the subselect doesn't do anything useful; you can just order by substring...